# Trying to render image from grayscale camera with OpenCV in C++. Hangs after a few frames

Tags: c++, opencv, raspbian, grayscale, raspberry-pi2

I have a grayscale camera (NOT COLOR) and am trying to render the image.  I am running on Raspbian, on a Raspberry Pi 2.  I've grabbed some code and bared it to a minimum and made some progress:

```
    #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    int main(int, char**)
    {
        VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
        if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
            return -1;
        bool rtn;
//        rtn = cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH , 752);
//        cout << "set to 752:" << rtn << endl;
//        rtn = cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT , 480);
//        cout << "set to 480:" << rtn << endl;
        int count = 1;
        Mat edges;
        namedWindow("edges",1);
        for(;;)
        {
            Mat frame;
            cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
            cout << "cols:" <<frame.cols << endl;
            cout << "rows:" << frame.rows << endl;
            cout << "count:" << count++ << endl;
            cout << "Channel Count:"<< frame.channels() << endl;
  //        cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            imshow("edges", edges);
            if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
        }
        // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
        return 0;
    }.
```

Now I get grayscale image, but it only runs for a few (2-4, it varies) frames, then hangs. 
Interestingly, if you wait long enough, sometimes it will scan a few more frames after "select timeout" messages.

I have tried running the following before running the application but it doesn't seem to help:

```
rmmod uvcvideo
modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=5000
```

Also, even though I specify the camera resolution as 720x480 (per the camera spec), it reports the frame size as 640x480.

It seems that when I take the following code out:

```
cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

It works, but it is not a grayscale image, it is green.  Note that I have commented out setting the frame width and height.

Comment: why are you splitting a single channel matrix (you told the camera output is grayscale)?

Comment: I tried using the image as captured, but it is green.

Comment: If it's grayscale it can be green :D you're probably just showing it wrong

Comment: Right, THAT's why I am trying find the image in the Mat and why I am asking for help ;-)

Comment: Glad you make to this point. I don't know why it hangs (it works ok on my pc), but some properties are not supported by all cameras. Check if your `double retval = cap.set(...)` returns 0. In that case the camera doesn't support that.

Comment: Just confirmed that setting both horizontal and vertical return 0.  Still no joy :-(

Comment: frame.channels() returns 3. I tried changing the waitKey to 1 but it still hangs after a few frames.

Comment: This seems to be a problem specific to the rasperry, since the code is perfectly fine. Probably you'll have better luck on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In the rasperrypi site it says probably is something with the video drivers. Can you update them?

Comment: I did apt-get update and upgrade recently

Answer (score 1):

Since you are capturing frames from camera, it captures a frame whenever the frame is ready so you don't need to wait for 30 ms, only 1 ms is enough, also before converting a frame to gray, ensure that it has 3 channels(as RGB or BGR frame).

by the way, the cv::VideoCapture::Set function may not working on some devices or some properties. To setting image dimension you should check accepted sizes of you camera, for example it may only accept 320x200, 640x480, 600x800, ...

Comment: 30 is ok, since it's 33 fps, but changing to 1 will be better. However, this doesn't explain why it hangs. If conversion wasn't ok, it will have thrown an assertion failure, so it's ok.

Comment: The camera specification is 752x480 (https://www.leopardimaging.com/LI-USB30-V034.html)

Comment: @Nima this still doesn't answer the question. This should be a comment, not an answer. If something isn't clear, or you think that something could actually help but you're not sure, put it in a comment. If it turns out to answer the question, you can then post an answer.

Comment: I opened a question on the raspberry pi forum but I am getting better responses here...

Comment: I am still stuck here :-(

Comment: can you check in which line it hangs. if it hangs when you are getting new frame it may happens because of problem in camera driver. can you test it with other cameras to ensure this.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I have a power issue.  I increased the power from the pi board (there is a setting in /boot/config.txt to do this) and that was not enough.  I added a USB power splitter and used a bench power supply.